# JavaDoc error: Use of standard constructor that does not provide a comment

Tags: javadoc

When I run the Javadoc code (provided by my university) it shows: Use of standard constructor that does not provide a comment.
I don't really know what I should do/change, so that the error goes away.

Every class has comments and every comment end with a dot.
FYI I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.

Example:

```java
/**
 *  This class provides a standardized structure for document formatting,
 *  with a specific focus on handling preconditions using assertions.
 *
 * @author XXX,
 * <a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.com">
 * XXX</a>
 */
public abstract class AbstractDocumentFormatter implements DocumentFormatter {....
```

Tried ending every comment with a dot.

Comment: maybe show us the constructor code? It's warning right?